# In Django REST Framework, why do serializers properly handle field-level validation exceptions in models but not object-level validation?

Tags: django, validation, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

To illustrate my problem, let's say I have a simple `Person` model defined like this:

```
from django.db import models
from django.core.validators import MinLengthValidator, MaxLengthValidator, ValidationError

class Person(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False, blank=False,
                                  validators=[MinLengthValidator(limit_value=1),
                                              MaxLengthValidator(limit_value=100)])
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True,
                                 validators=[MinLengthValidator(limit_value=1),
                                             MaxLengthValidator(limit_value=100)])

    def clean(self):
        self.validate()
        super().clean()

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.full_clean()
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    def validate(self):
        """The first and last names cannot be the same strings."""
        if (self.first_name and self.last_name and
                self.first_name.lower() == self.last_name.lower()):
            raise ValidationError('First and last names, if both are provided, cannot be the same.',
                                  code='invalid',
                                  params={'first_name': self.first_name,
                                          'last_name': self.last_name})
```

- Notice that both the `first_name` and `last_name` fields have *field-level* validation associated with them. (My dev database is SQLite, and it does not do length validation. So I had to add `validators`. But that is not my question.)

I defined two simple `APIView`-based classes:

```
from rest_framework import generics
from ..models import Person
from ..serializers import PersonSerializer

class PersonDetailView(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    name = 'person-detail'
    queryset = Person.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PersonSerializer
    lookup_field = 'id'

class PersonListView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    name = 'person-list'
    queryset = Person.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PersonSerializer
    lookup_field = 'id'
```

I defined a serializer based on Django REST Framework's `ModelSerializer`:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from ..models import Person

class PersonSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Person
        fields = ('id', 'first_name', 'last_name')
```

And, I mapped some URLs.

If I POST, PUT, or PATCH such that I violate the **field-level** validation rules (e.g., I try to submit a first name that is 101 character long), Django REST Framework catches the exception from the model class and displays it appropriately. Here's what it looks like in the browsable API:

[image]

But, if I POST, PUT, or PATCH such that I violate the **object-level** validation rule, Django REST framework does not catch the exception, and the server crashes and displays a trace like this:

[image]

My solution has been to add object-level validation to the serializer as well as to the model. Here's the serializer with its own `validate` method:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from rest_framework.validators import ValidationError

from ..models import Person

class PersonSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Person
        fields = ('id', 'first_name', 'last_name')

    def validate(self, attrs):
        first_name = attrs.get('first_name')
        last_name = attrs.get('last_name')
        if first_name and last_name and first_name.lower() == last_name.lower():
            raise ValidationError('First and last names must be different.',
                                  code='invalid')
        return attrs
```

If I do this, then Django REST Framework handles the exception just fine:

[image]

Here (finally ;-) are my questions:

> Why do I have to perform **object-level** validation in *both* the model and the serializer when I only have to do **field-level** validation in the model and the serializer will handle the exceptions just fine?
>
> Is this how Django REST Framework is intended to behave? Seems like the serializer should be able to gracefully handle *all* `ValidationError`s raised by the model.

Answer (score 3):

Post DRF 3.0, `.clean()` method will not be called as part of serializer validation, as it would be if using a ModelForm, read this https://www.django-rest-framework.org/community/3.0-announcement/#differences-between-modelserializer-validation-and-modelform.

Comment: This is key insight - the link even provides code on how to solve the problem

Answer (score 2):

It does. You need to put a [validation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#validation) method in serializer:

```
class PersonSerializer(serializer.ModelSerializer):

    def validate_first_name(self, value):
        if len(value)> 100:
            raise serializer.ValidationError("Can't be more than 100")
        return value
```

Comment: I'm curious. Why can't DRF handle object-level validation rules?

Comment: rudder -- That's exactly my point. WHY do I have to have a validation method in *both* the model and the serializer when the serializers handles field-level validation exceptions from the model just fine? It's only the object-level validation exceptions from the model that the serializer cannot handle.

Comment: @SeanFrancisN.Ballais It handles object level validation: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#object-level-validation.
And for @SteveWehba 's point, um, unfortunately drf does not handle django core validation error. but it handles restframework.serializer.validationerror. And you can still throw it from model clean method, it will work regardless. Well, if you want to put those validations in model and throw django validation exception, then you need to put `serializer.save()` block in a try catch.